# Why are (Pages for Mac) templates, in the Library folder different than what's available in Pages?

Tags: macos, pages

Mac's Pages templates seem to be stored in:

```
Library/Application Support/iWork/Pages/Templates/My Templates
```

However, when I use Pages and wish to choose a template, what's available is different than what's in the Library folder.

Can anyone explain this discrepancy?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Mac OS X are you running on your Mac? What version of Pages are you having problems with? In which Library folder are you looking: Macintosh HD/Users/your_username/Library/Application Support... or Macintosh HD/Library/Application Support....?

Answer (score 1):

The pre-installed templates are stored within the application bundle. You find them by right-clicking the Pages application in the Applications folder and choosing 'Show Package Contents…', then navigating into the subfolder Contents—>Resources—>Templates.

The 'MyTemplates' folder is meant as a standard folder for templates you create yourself.

(based on Pages 4.3)